# Sort List of Parent / Child Objects

Tags: linq, sorting

I am having some trouble figuring out how to efficiently sort a list of parent items based on the child items.

I cannot just sort the child items. I need the result of the child item sort to affect the sorting of the parent list.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is sort the Parents in an order that reflects their children's name in descending order.

Is there a "linqish" way to do this once I already have a list of parents in memory? If so, any help you could afford would be great.

Here is an example....

```
//What I am trying to do is to figure out how to sort the order of parent1, parent2, parent3 
//based on the names of their children. 
//More specifically, the expected output would be:
//parent 1 (because she has a child with the name of Zoey), 
//parent 3 (because she has a child next in desc order with the name of Yolanda), 
//parent 2 (because her child names in desc order would Matt).

public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    //some properties
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public static List<Parent> GetSortedParentsByChildName()
    {
        List<Parent> myUnsortedList = new List<Parent>()
        {
            new Parent()
            {
                id = 1,
                Children = new List<Child>()
                {
                    new Child(1, "Billy"),
                    new Child(1, "Zoey"),
                    new Child(1, "Robert"),
                }
            },
            new Parent()
            {
                id = 2,
                Children = new List<Child>()
                {
                    new Child(1, "Gabe"),
                    new Child(1, "Matt"),
                    new Child(1, "Alyssa"),
                }
            },
            new Parent()
            {
                id = 3,
                Children = new List<Child>()
                {
                    new Child(1, "Will"),
                    new Child(1, "Bob"),
                    new Child(1, "Yolanda"),
                }
            },
        };


        return myUnsortedList; //.OrderBy(my actual question);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    //some properties
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child(int id, string Name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;

    }
}
```

Comment: Any Sample Input\ Output you are expecting?

Comment: List<Parent> mySortedParents = ?????Some magical way to sort all parents by children's name descending???

Comment: What `SortOrder` column is for?

Comment: Default SortOrder. But the end user could request to see Parents in a different order by children's name descending....

Comment: @Saolo812- Why i asked you show some sample data was because your Type is a bit confusing. Your `Parent` class contains `List<Child>` so that itself will be sorted. Please add some sample data.

Comment: I have edited the post to have a mostly working function. The part I'm missing is the sort logic. I hope this makes things a little easier to understand.

Comment: Why you are adding parent again to child object? Your above code will obviously throw null reference exception.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. I removed it for clarity.

Comment: Okay, So here comes my first question again, Why you are considering just 1 child withing each parent? What about the rest of them?

Comment: The why's are in the comments. No further explanation of business rules is going to add any value.

Comment: Hmm got it! Have added my answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so you can do it in this way as well:-

```
List<Parent> mySortedList =
    myUnsortedList
        .OrderByDescending(
            x => x.Children.OrderByDescending(z => z.Name).First().Name)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: If you took out the `[0]` I'd say this was a pretty good answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yup.. I was also thinking the same :) Now its better?

Comment: Looks good to me. I've upvoted and I think you should get the accepted answer.

Comment: This code works as well and I think it's a little easier to read as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to replace the `return` line in `GetSortedParentsByChildName`:

```
        var childrenMap =
            myUnsortedList
                .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
                .Select(x => x.Name)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(n => n)
                .Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.n, x => x.i);

        return myUnsortedList
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x,
                max = x.Children
                    .Select(y => childrenMap[y.Name])
                    .Max()
            })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.max)
            .Select(x => x.x)
            .ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: parents in order]